# Rust: View entire Command::New command arguement structs as its passed to terminal / correct my arguements

Tags: linux, rust

I am not getting the correct response from the server running the following

```
Command::new("curl")
       .args(&["-X",
        "POST",
        "--header",
        &("Authorization: Bearer ".to_owned() + &return_token("auth")),
        "--header",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "-d",
        parameters,
        "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/CORRECT_ACCOUNT_#/orders",
    ])
    .output()
    .unwrap()
    .stdout;

Command::new("curl")
         .arg("-X")
         .arg("POST")
         .arg("--header")
         .arg("Authorization: Bearer ".to_owned() + &return_token("auth"))
         .arg("--header")
         .arg("Content-Type: application/json")
         .arg("-d")
         .arg(parameters)
         .arg("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/CORRECT_ACCOUNT_#/orders")
    .output()
    .unwrap()
    .stdout;
```

However.... the following works fine if I run it in terminal. I form the following using `let line = "curl -X POST --header \"Authorization: Bearer ".to_owned() + &return_token("auth") + "\" --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d " + parameters + " \"https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/CORRECT_ACCOUNT_#/orders\"";`

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer LONG_RANDOM_AUTH_TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{
\"complexOrderStrategyType\": \"NONE\",
\"orderType\": \"LIMIT\",
\"session\": \"NORMAL\",
\"price\": \"0.01\",
\"duration\": \"DAY\",
\"orderStrategyType\": \"SINGLE\",
\"orderLegCollection\": [
  {
    \"instruction\": \"BUY_TO_OPEN\",
    \"quantity\": 1,
    \"instrument\": {
      \"symbol\": \"SPY_041621P190\",
      \"assetType\": \"OPTION\"
  }
  }
]
}" "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/CORRECT_ACCOUNT_#/orders"
```

"parameters" can be seen above in JSON.

How can do I view the formation of the command that Command::New is making or correct my args?

**EDIT** Ive tried using a single quote around the JSON and not escaping the double quotes, which also works in the terminal.

**EDIT** Example included. I found this : https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29494 && https://users.rust-lang.org/t/std-process-is-escaping-a-raw-string-literal-when-i-dont-want-it-to/19441/14

However Im in linux...

```
fn main() {

// None of the following work

let parameters = r#"{"complexOrderStrategyType":"NONE","orderType":"LIMIT","session":"NORMAL","price":"0.01","duration":"DAY","orderStrategyType":"SINGLE","orderLegCollection":[{"instruction":"BUY_TO_OPEN","quantity":1,"instrument":{"symbol":"SPY_041621P190","assetType":"OPTION"}}]}"#;

// OR

let parameters = "'{\"complexOrderStrategyType\":\"NONE\",\"orderType\": \"LIMIT\",\"session\": \"NORMAL\",\"price\": \"0.01\",\"duration\": \"DAY\",\"orderStrategyType\": \"SINGLE\",\"orderLegCollection\": [{\"instruction\": \"BUY_TO_OPEN\",\"quantity\": 1,\"instrument\": {\"symbol\": \"SPY_041621P190\",\"assetType\": \"OPTION\"}}]}'";

// OR 

let parameters = "{\"complexOrderStrategyType\":\"NONE\",\"orderType\": \"LIMIT\",\"session\": \"NORMAL\",\"price\": \"0.01\",\"duration\": \"DAY\",\"orderStrategyType\": \"SINGLE\",\"orderLegCollection\": [{\"instruction\": \"BUY_TO_OPEN\",\"quantity\": 1,\"instrument\": {\"symbol\": \"SPY_041621P190\",\"assetType\": \"OPTION\"}}]}";

// OR 

let parameters = "{'complexOrderStrategyType':'NONE','orderType': 'LIMIT','session': 'NORMAL','price': '0.01','duration': 'DAY','orderStrategyType': 'SINGLE','orderLegCollection': [{'instruction': 'BUY_TO_OPEN','quantity': 1,'instrument': {'symbol': 'SPY_041621P190','assetType': 'OPTION'}}]}";

    println!("{:?}", str::from_utf8(&curl(parameters, "ORDER")).unwrap());

    fn curl(parameters: &str, request_type: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut output = Vec::new();

        if request_type == "ORDER" {
            output = Command::new("curl")
                .args(&[
                    "-X",
                    "POST",
                    "--header",
                    "Authorization: Bearer AUTH_KEY_NOT_INCLUDED",
                    "--header",
                    "Content-Type: application/json",
                    "-d",
                    parameters,
                    "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER_NOT_INCLUDED/orders",
                ])
                .output()
                .unwrap()
                .stdout;
        }
        output
    }
}
```

Comment: `Command` implements `Debug` so you can [print it out](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bce06fa658ffa77c54f9745e0008d237) to see if there's any weird encoding problems. Do you have any indication whether its the token, body, or url that's the issue?

Comment: Note that `Command` does not spawn a shell to run your commands. That means that the arguments are not subject to shell expansion, quoting, etc. If you are passing your JSON parameters with backslashed quotes nothing will remove the backslashes.

Comment: @harmic, thank you for responding. I used a a single quote around the parameters and removed the backslashes and still got the same error. But it works fine in the terminal

Comment: @kmdreko, thank you! but it turns out... to be less useful than expected... :/

Comment: @harmic, how do I spawn a new shell and run the command in it?

Comment: @harmic Ive tried `let line = "curl -X POST --header 'Authorization: Bearer ".to_owned()  + &return_token("auth")  + "' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@orders.json' 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT/orders'";
                            
        println!( "{:?}",  Command::new("bash").arg("--rcfile")
                .arg("<(echo '. ~/.bashrc; ".to_owned() + &line.replace("'", \"") + "')")`

Comment: @harmic, looks like escape characters are added even when removed

Comment: raw string is a no go.. :/

Comment: Could you update your question to show a whole example, including where you assign the variable `parameters`? It is very hard to give advice with a partial example.

Comment: @harmic done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons unknown... changing the --header switch / flag to -H solved the problem. As shown in the following. Spoke with a friend and apparently the shortened form may take different parameters.

```
let parameters = "{
\"complexOrderStrategyType\": \"NONE\",
\"orderType\": \"LIMIT\",
\"session\": \"NORMAL\",
\"price\": \"0.01\",
\"duration\": \"DAY\",
\"orderStrategyType\": \"SINGLE\",
\"orderLegCollection\": [
  {
    \"instruction\": \"BUY_TO_OPEN\",
    \"quantity\": 1,
    \"instrument\": {
      \"symbol\": \"SPY_041621P190\",
      \"assetType\": \"OPTION\"
  }
  }
]
}";

 Command::new("curl")
    .args(&["-X",
    "POST",
    "-H",
    &("Authorization: Bearer ".to_owned() + &return_token("auth")),
    "-H",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "-d",
    parameters,
    "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT/orders",
])
.output()
.unwrap()
.stdout;
```